# how to divide my html into parts using canvas and resize it fit browser window

Tags: html, html5-canvas, render

I'm new to webpage development and now little about html.

Div tag will be used to divide webpage into different sections but how i can do this
using canvas or even with div tag. For reference please see the attached image page-division.

[image]

I want to divide as shown above.

Also these divisions should resize as per window of browser also.
I tried 2-3 options but it did not work well.

do i need to write in javascript ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overview**

What you are asking about is generally known as "responsive" design.

That's a big topic!  Here's a link to an introduction of responsive design:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

You ask about scaling, but responsive design also involves moving content based on the device size.

For example if your design above is viewed on a phone you might want the red and green sections to stack below the blue sections. You can use CSS to move your content based on resizing events.

**Now to your answer.**

Canvas is often used to present graphs and other visual information.

For example, your red rectangle might contain a graph using a canvas

Your canvas (your graph) can be scaled like this:

```
// the original size of your red rect
// this is the red width at "full size"

var originalWidth=450;
var originalHeight=125;

// new max values for your red rect
// this example assumes the user resizes their browser to less width

var maxWidth=300;
var maxHeight=125;

// now resize the canvas while maintaining aspect ratio
// so your graph does not distort

var scaleFactor=Math.min((maxWidth/originalWidth),(maxHeight/originalHeight));

// resize the canvas element proportionally

canvas.width=originalWidth*scaleFactor;
canvas.height=originalHeight*scaleFactor;

// A gotcha!  When you resize the canvas all its content is erased.
// Therefore, you must redraw your graph to the canvas

// scale the canvas

context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);

// now redraw your graph as you originally did
// context.scale will take care of all the scaling for you!
```

Comment: markE... i don't it see on phone at all.. only as webpage on laptop or monitor

Comment: Ok, if you don't need mobile, then you can use the scale code in my answer.  Cheers!